# Mongosink Connector to exclude topice

Tags: regex, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have mongo sink connector for my kafka cluster which sinks topic data into mongo database.
I am looking for properties to exclude one topic in my sink connector if there is any.

Explanation:

1. **local.test.data**
2. **local.test.data-status**
3. **local.test.dataClone**

this 3 are my topic in kafka and my sink topic.regex is local.test.* but i don't want to sink local.test.data-status and i need to exclude this particular topic for sinking.

Is there an property available to perform this

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to only capture the topics you want

```
local.test.data(Clone)?
```

Or use `topics` with a CSV list instead of `topic.regex`